# Is there a way in JavaScript to directly get the content width of an element when box-sizing:border-box is set in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If we set this in CSS (autoprefixed):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

then `getComputedStyle(elem).width` includes the element's padding.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/EpUnp/

I would like to get the width of the element's content box (without the padding). Is there a **standard API** for this or do I have to manually subtract the padding?

Comment: I *think* you have to, but "I think" isn't an answer. :-)

Comment: I too am almost certain you have to calculate it yourself (though it should only be a very simple function).

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/

Comment: @Paulie_D jQuery of course has its little, neat methods for this, but I'm curious if the Web Platform itself provides an API for this.

Comment: @Teemu …but *with* the padding -.-

Comment: Looking at the jquery fix for this, that's exactly what they did: subtracted border and padding when border-box is set. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/d7217cc29c24f582198ce2df7db54a55625e8259

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Turns out, there is a standard API for this, but it's only supported in Firefox (for now).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Apparently it's "at risk" though. Not so much a standard API as the beginnings of something that may, at some point, possibly become standard in some form. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The latest CSSOM View editor's draft is from January 9th and Firefox landed this API around the end of March. I hope that means that it's no longer at risk :)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Well, it still [says it is](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#the-geometryutils-interface).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My point was that this draft is from January, *before* it was implemented in Firefox. Not sure how old this API is, but when an API has no implementations, that can trigger an "at risk" flag. With Firefox's implementation, this flag could very well be lifted in the next editor's draft.

Answer (score 5):

The [getBoxQuads API](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/introducing-the-getboxquads-api/) can do it. (It's supported in Firefox Nightly).

```
var quad = elem.getBoxQuads({ box: 'content' })[0];
var contentWidth = quad.p2.x - quad.p1.x;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EpUnp/2/ (works in Firefox Nightly)

[image]

Comment: @mastaBlasta 1. Standard API means published by W3C, ECMA, etc., 2. Firefox Nightly means that it will be available in Firefox in a few months.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a standard API for this. I could be wrong though.

My approach would be something like as follows.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2N8jC/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
#box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    padding:14px 10px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var supports = function () {
    var div = document.createElement("div"),
        vendors = "Moz Webkit O Ms".split(" "),
        len = vendors.length;

    return function (prop) {
        if (prop in div.style) return true;

        prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function (val) {
            return val.toUpperCase();
        });

        while (len--) {
            if (vendors[len] + prop in div.style) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
};

var isBox = supports("box-sizing");

var getWidth = function (elem) {
    var width = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(box).width);
    var padding = window.getComputedStyle(box).padding.split(" ");

    if (!isBox) {
        return width;
    }

    switch (padding.length) {
        case 4:
            return width - (parseFloat(padding[1]) + parseFloat(padding[3]));
            break;
        case 2:
            return width - (parseFloat(padding[1]) * 2);
            break;
        default:
            return width - (parseFloat(padding[0]) * 2);
            break;
    }
}

var box = document.getElementById("box");

alert(getWidth(box));
```

Rough and ready but seems to work :)